# How to validate a jwt token programmatically in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

Using **[LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle)**, it is possible to validate a passed token **within a controller**?

p.s. I am aware that I can do `$this->getUser()` that returns the User if the user was authenticated and `null` otherwise. But that is not what I'm after.

I wish to know if there is something of the sort `isTokenValid('the-token-string');` that gives a *true/false* response ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inject JWTEncoderInterface to  your controller,

```
public function __construct(JWTEncoderInterface $jwtEncoder)
{
  $this->jwtEncoder = $jwtEncoder;
}
```

then in your method you can  decode the token like this

```
try {
      $this->jwtEncoder->decode($token);

    } catch (JWTDecodeFailureException $ex) {
            // if no exception thrown then the token could be used
    }
```

if no exception  is thrown then the token could be used. be aware that the exception is thrown if

- token is not valid
- token is expired
- token is not verified

but if you want to specifically know which one is occurred you should inject
 JWSProviderInterface to your controller

```
public function __construct(JWSProviderInterface $jwsProvider)
{
  $this->jwsProvider = $jwsProvider;
}
```

and in your method call load action of it like this

```
try{
      $jws = $this->jwsProvider->load($token);

   }catch(\Exception $e){

   }

   if (!$jws->isInvalid()) {
         //if  token is valid
    }

    if (!$jws->isExpired()) {
         //if  token is not expired
   }

   if ($jws->isVerified()) {
        //if  token is verified
   }
```

Comment: You don't need to use jws provider to check that, the `JWTDecodeFailureException` also contains method `getReason()` which you can check against the constants: `JWTDecodeFailureException::EXPIRED_TOKEN`, `JWTDecodeFailureException::UNVERIFIED_TOKEN`, `JWTDecodeFailureException::INVALID_TOKEN`.